# Is there a medical condition in which you can't cut your hair?

Tags: hair

Just curious, does there exist a medical condition in which a patient is advised not to or simply cannot cut their (head) hair?

Comment: Hair is not alive, so there shouldn't be any problems with that.

Comment: Patients on blood thinners are advised to avoid cutting risks, which would suggest "no shaving", but presumably depilation by other means would not have that risk.

Comment: What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An phobia or OCD released to appearance might lead someone to face dire situations when their hair is cut even death if the fear leads to a heart attack.

Comment: I like this one

Answer (score 2):

Alopecia and balding, these individual experience hair loss, thus nothing to cut